# Comparing and increasing string value with FOR loop

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop

I'm trying to compare new string against old string from database, and if that string exists increase it by one, for example if string **car** exists new string should be **car-1** and if that string exist then **car-2**...

I'm using Laravel, and have achieved that by using **while()** loop, but I would like to do it with **for()** loop too.

This is my code that works:

```
foreach($lang_codes as $key => $value)
{               
    $oldAlias = str_slug($request->{"new_category_lang_{$value->code}"}, '-');
    $newAlias = $oldAlias;
    $aliasCheck = ShopCategoryName::where('alias', $oldAlias)->first();
    $newCategory = new ShopCategoryName;

    $i = 1;
    while ($aliasCheck) 
    {
        $newAlias = $oldAlias . '-' . $i;
        $aliasCheck = ShopCategoryName::where('alias', $newAlias)->first();
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I was trying to use **strcmp()** with **for()** loop, but I don't know how to put that code together, it was mess.

So basically, I'm trying code above to work with **for()** loop, but my brain has blocked and overcomplicated.

Comment: I don't see what the change of loop would do. Also, that code appears to be solving some problem, yet you're asking about swapping one loop for the other - that would make no difference to code style or readability. What would make the difference is deleting that code and let your DB do all the work. We've got triggers, we've got stored procedures, we've got events - all of those are powerful tools that you can use to have your database contain the data you *want*. Wouldn't any of those solve your problem in such a way that would let you simply delete this piece of code?

Comment: Because I would like to learn how to do it with **for** loop, that is all. Writing code in a different way!

Comment: As @N.B. explained, your while loop is actually ideal for this scenario. Why? Because your loop is based on true or false (while $aliasCheck exists, do this). Trying to write this in for loop will result in more code being written. For loops are better when you have a know end point, e.g: insering 10 items in the database would work best with a for loop (`for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { }`).

Comment: Using while loop is fine, using for loop is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part

```
$i = 1;
while ($aliasCheck) 
{
    $newAlias = $oldAlias . '-' . $i;
    $aliasCheck = ShopCategoryName::where('alias', $newAlias)->first();
    $i++;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for ($i = 1; $aliasCheck; $i++) 
{
    $newAlias = $oldAlias . '-' . $i;
    $aliasCheck = ShopCategoryName::where('alias', $newAlias)->first();
}
```

You can also rewrite your code to:

```
$oldAlias = str_slug($request->{"new_category_lang_{$value->code}"}, '-');
$newAlias = $oldAlias;
$newCategory = new ShopCategoryName; // <-- not sure what that is good for

for ($i = 1; ShopCategoryName::where('alias', $newAlias)->exists(); ++$i) 
{
    $newAlias = $oldAlias . '-' . $i;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, never would have thought of that simple solution.
I didn even knew that I could write **for** loop with just variable without giving it conditional operator.

**$newCategory = new ShopCategoryName; // <-- not sure what that is  good for** =>this is another part of the code that creates new row in datatable after checking if alias exists, since it didn`t matter for this guestion I˙v cut it out.

Thanks for solution

Comment: I have a question regarding last piece of code, when I put 
`ShopCategoryName::where('alias', $newAlias)->exists();`
in a variable I got **FatalErrorException in ShopsController.php line 346: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded**, it works fine when full query is written, like you have done. Why is that? And, does `++$i` instead of `$i++` have something with how values are returned?

`++$i` will increment the value of `$i`, and then return the incremented value, while `$i++` will increment the value of `$i`, but return the value that `$i` held before being incremented.

Comment: The value of your variable does not change inside the loop. So if its TRUE at the beginning, it will remain TRUE and the loop will not exit (endless loop). Your description of the ++ operators is correct. Logically there is no difference if you don't use the returned values. But `++$i` is a little bit faster (like 2%).